# play framework template and dynamic code in quotes

Tags: templates, playframework, routes, playframework-2.0

I need to make a list of users. I am trying to do it this way:

```
<a href="user/{user.id}">{user.fullname}</a>
```

But it doesn't evaluate {user.id} so my links are all like "www.example.com/user/{user.id}". What is a correct form how to do it? user.fullname was all right so I supposed that it will work in quotes too but it doesn't.

Comment: @user.id should work, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed `Play 1.x` and `Play 2.x` templating engines! Take a look to the documentation and included samples!

in Play 2 it would be rather something like:

```
<a href="@routes.Application.showUser(user.id)">@user.fullname</a>
```